# My App stopped working/displaying on chrome web

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, mobile, file-upload

crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

I was expecting my image i uploaded through the pubspec.yaml, through the Assest image to appear on the chrome browser, instead it showing me:

http://localhost:8080/
This site can't be reached.
Pls i need help.